# open new window in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to open new window from existing one in pyqt.

My source code has two functions.

one functions : when button is clicked, File Dialog is opened.
another functions : when another button is clicked, New Window is opened.

But When I want to New window, error message occurs :

- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
  "C:\Users\Han\Desktop\project\prototype\newwindow.py", line 61, in
  check_start
     self.w.show() AttributeError: 'Ui_dialog' object has no attribute 'show'

  ```
  from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

  try:
      _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
  except AttributeError:
  def _fromUtf8(s):
      return s

  try:
      _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
      def _translate(context, text, disambig):
          return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
  except AttributeError:
      def _translate(context, text, disambig):
          return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

  class Ui_Form(object):
      def setupUi(self, Form):
          Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
          Form.resize(518, 349)
          self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
          self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 141, 16))
          self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
          self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
          self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 330, 141, 16))
          self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
          self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(Form)
          self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 200, 381, 31))
          self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayoutWidget"))
          self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
          self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
          self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
          self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
          self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
          self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
          self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
          self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
          self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
          self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 270, 75, 23))
          self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))

          self.retranslateUi(Form)
          QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.file_open)
          QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.check_start)
          QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

      def retranslateUi(self, Form):
          Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Off_Strip", None))
           self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "123", None))
          self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "@Copyright MokLab", None))
          self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "123", None))
          self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "123!", None))

      def file_open(self):
          fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
          f = open(fname, 'r')
          f.close()

      def check_start(self):
          self.w = Ui_dialog()
          self.w.show()

  class Ui_dialog(object):
      def setupUi(self, dialog):
          dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dialog"))
          dialog.resize(400, 300)
          self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog)
          self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 130, 75, 23))
          self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
          self.radioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(dialog)
          self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 90, 16))
          self.radioButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton"))
          self.radioButton_2 = QtGui.QRadioButton(dialog)
          self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 90, 16))
          self.radioButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton_2"))

          self.retranslateUi(dialog)
          QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog)

      def retranslateUi(self, dialog):
          dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("dialog", "Form", None))
          self.pushButton.setText(_translate("dialog", "PushButton", None))
          self.radioButton.setText(_translate("dialog", "RadioButton", None))
          self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("dialog", "RadioButton", None))

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      import sys
      app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
      Form = QtGui.QWidget()
      ui = Ui_Form()
      ui.setupUi(Form)
      Form.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use basic formatting options.

Comment: anyone who i don't know completed it.. thank you!